# Euler's method to solve a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

> Apply Euler's method on the initial value problem $y'(t)=y(t)$ with $y(0)=1$ (in the interval $[0,1]$) and equidistant grid $I_h$, $h=\frac1n$. Give the approximation $y_h$ explicitly.

This question is a little bit related to: [fixpoint iteration to solve $y'(t)=y(t), y(0)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230924/fixpoint-iteration-to-solve-yt-yt-y0-1)

So I want to use Euler's method for the given IVP.

The method is stated as follows:

$y_{k+1}=y_k+hf(t_k, y_k)$

Here, we have $f(t_k,y_k)=y_k$ because of the differential equation $y'=y$.

So we get:

$y_1=y_0+\frac1n\cdot y_0=1+\frac1n\cdot 1=1+\frac1n$

$y_2=y_1+\frac1n\cdot y_1=1+\frac1n+\frac{1}{n}+\frac1{n^2}=1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$

And so on. An explicit formula is given by:

$y_m=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}$

I doubt, that this is correct.
First of all this does not depend on $t$, and I am asked to show, that

$y_h(1)\to_{n\to\infty} y(1)=e$

Can you help me out?
What have I done wrong? Is it correct to set $f(t_k, y_k)=y_k$?

Comment: It's correct. If you don't expand the product you get a simpler formula $y_k = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$ and $y_h(1) = y_n$. This is perhaps a more [familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History) limit to you.

Comment: @Winther Oh, of course, did not thought about the binomial formula. Thank you. But what is $y_h(1)$ supposed to mean here? What would $y_h(0)$ or $y_h(1/2)$ be?

Comment: You have $x_k = k/n$ so $y_h(x_k) = y_k = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^k = \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^{x_k} \approx e^{x_k}$.

Comment: @Winther So $x_k$ is a value in the grid $I_h$? With $y_h(1)=y_n=(1+\frac1n)^n$ it is clear, that this converges to $e$. How do I see, that $y_h(x_k)=y_k$ tho? I struggle, because I have not used this $x_k$ so far, so I am not sure where it comes from. Besides that, it is clear, since $1=\frac{n}{n}=x_n$ and then $y_h(x_n)=y_n=(1+\frac1n)^n\to e$, as you stated.

Comment: I used the wrong letter. Should be $t_k$ which is what you use. The value $y_k$ is the value at the $k$'th step. You take steps of size $1/n$ starting at $t=0$ so $t_k = k/n$.

Comment: @Winther Ah ok, thank you. You mean steps of size $1/n$, instead of $1/h$, I guess.

Comment: Yes. I fixed it now!

Comment: @Winther Great. If you make an answer out of your comments, I can accept it, if you mind.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. Too tired to write up anything right now.